# Turn Off Red and Green Squigglies in Microsoft Word Per Document

Tags: microsoft-word

I know how to turn off the red and green squigglies for a document that I am viewing. But how do I turn it off for the document so if someone else opens and reads it the squigglies are hidden regardless of their settings?

Answer (score 2):

Send it as a PDF?

Seriously, those are indicators of grammar or spelling issues.  You should fix them all! If you don't want them seen, send it as a non-word document.  Otherwise their local grammar and spell check will discover them.

Comment: To be fair, sometimes you're using a word that isn't in the dictionary (add it to the dictionary, although for names you may not want to do this) or a grammatical construction that's valid or necessary.  The grammar detection still isn't THAT great...